# Get the session name of a parent gnu screen

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I know that the current session name can be accessed with the `$STY` environment variable, is there a way to get the session name of the parent screen session in case of nested screens?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible; `$STY` is really the only place to get this information and the old value is masked by the nested screen.  You could rename `screen` to `screen-real` and replace it with a shell script that did something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$STY" ]; then
    export PARENT_STY=$STY
fi
exec $0-real "$@"
```

This would get you access to $PARENT_STY inside a nested screen, but it would only work for a single level of nesting.  If you really wanted to you could get substantially more complicated (e.g., treating `PARENT_STY` like a list and appending values), but that doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Maybe `screen -ls` helps.